# When you exactly need Http://localhost:5000 to retrieve data from Database?

Tags: database, rest, localhost

for example I have two database server, one is on the cloud and one is on the company server.

I use `http://localhost:3000` to 'GET' Data from the database, it works fine if the database is on my client or on company server.
But on the cloud variante, can I also use localhost to retrieve data? because the cloud database doesn't have Rest-APIs. Or do I need to programm a REST-API Interface with node.js express?
Do you need a webserver to use localhost?

So I am not sure, when I can use localhost. Hope someone can explain me that question.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

Does your program run locally on the cloud web server? Or does it run on a client machine on the internet?

For the former, you can use http://localhost:3000 as it will locally resolve correctly. This assumes that the production cloud web server has connectivity to the production database server.

For the latter (any machine other than your dev machine), localhost will resolve to the client machine which won't have the web service and will fail.

It may not be a good idea to run your program on the production cloud web server, purely from a separation of concerns perspective.

Comment: I will hosted the app on the cloud and then it will retrieve the data from the cloud database

Comment: Is your 'app' a web app/website? How are other users expected to connect to it, if you don't expose the web app on a well known URL? You should not be using localhost, you should be using the public URL such as http://example.com:3000/ where your web app is deployed.